# How to sort a list per the occurrence of a part of each items (items are strings)?

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, slice

I want to sort the following word pool according to occurrence of their 3-letter suffix, from most frequent to least frequent:

```
wordPool = ['beat','neat','food','good','mood','wood','bike','like','mike']
```

Expected output:

```
['food','good','mood','wood','bike','like','mike','beat','neat']
```

For simplicity, only 4-letter-words are in the pool and the suffix is always 3-letter ones.

(Note: If the counts are the same, then order can be arbitrary.)

Comment: `sorted(wordPool, key=lambda s: s[:3], reverse=True)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.Counter()` to get the frequency of the suffixes, and then use `sort()` with a key parameter to sort by the generated frequencies:

```py
from collections import Counter
suffix_counters = Counter(s[-3:] for s in wordPool)
wordPool.sort(key=lambda x: suffix_counters[x[-3:]], reverse=True)
print(wordPool)
```

This outputs:

```py
['food', 'good', 'mood', 'wood', 'bike', 'like', 'mike', 'beat', 'neat']
```

Answer (score 0):

- Group by suffix using a `dict` of lists;
- Sort the groups by decreasing order of size;
- Join all the groups into a list.

```py
def sorted_by_suffix_frequency(wordpool, n=3):
    groups = {}
    for w in wordpool:
        groups.setdefault(w[-n:], []).append(w)
    return [w for g in sorted(groups.values(), key=len, reverse=True) for w in g]

wordpool = ['beat','neat','food','good','mood','wood','bike','like','mike']

sorted_wordpool = sorted_by_suffix_frequency(wordpool)

print(sorted_wordpool)
# ['food', 'good', 'mood', 'wood', 'bike', 'like', 'mike', 'beat', 'neat']
```